# Is it possible to configure sshd to use the current account in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, sshd

I'm currently using Cygwin on Windows 10. I've seen material such as [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281), or [this](http://techtorials.me/cygwin/sshd-configuration/) (which says the first source is outdated), and both of them revolve around running;

```
ssh-host-config
```

to configure sshd as a service. I was wondering how one would configure the Cygwin-based sshd to use the current (privileged) account for logins rather than a newly set up privileged account?

My best guess is to use the current privileged account name where it says:

```
Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no) yes
Enter the new user name: CurrentPrivAccount
Reenter: CurrentPrivAccount
```

Would this work? If not what would?

UPDATE

In

```
ssh-host-config
```

it says:

```
*** Query: Create new privileged user account (ect...)
```

That is what I want to avoid. Is there any way to use the current (privileged) account instead of creating a new one?

Comment: The privileged account is NOT for login but to start the demon as service.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out you don't have to create a new privileged account during the privileged account phase of;

```
ssh-host-config
```

It simply uses the current account, which has to have Administrator privileges for the Cygwin sshd daemon to work.